# What's a synonym for the profile of a mountain?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe the the contour of a mountain. Something like profile, or cross-section.

I've heard of [stratigraphic column](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratigraphic_column), but I think that requires showing the layers, like on the image below. I'm also interested in the name for maps that don't show the layers, just the profile.

[image: mountain profile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Elevation profile maps* are often used to show the ups and downs of trails for hikers and cyclists. (I know *elevation profile* is not a single word, but I think this might be the term you're after.)

See these links for examples of elevation profile maps, and of course you can Google the term:

> http://www.antigravitygear.com/shop/pocket-profiles-guides-books/pocket-profile-foothills-trail-elevation-profile-map/
>
> http://www.kta-hike.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=389&Itemid=80

Answer (score 1):

The [topographic prominence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_prominence) is the height of a the mountain in relation to its surroundings. A [topographic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_map) generally shows contour lines, but not the internals.